# what is the equivalent of substring for an array?

Tags: javascript

I simply want to extract the values of an array from [1] to the end.
Is this the only (or best) way to do it?

```
// example with a string
var stringy = "36781"
console.log(stringy.substring(1))

// example with an array
var array2 = [3,6,7,8,1]
array2.shift()
console.log(array2)
```

Comment: You probably want to use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: slice is it - thanks Mr. Khan

Comment: If you are ok with mutating the original shift works, if you want a new version slice(1);  if you want a really bad implementation for this use case: filter :)

Comment: Read documentation when you need to know what methods are available: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var array2 = [3,6,7,8,1];
array2.slice(1);
```

will produce `[6, 7, 8, 1]`

Note that `slice` copies the array's contents only one level deep. What that means *technically* is that nested arrays or objects within the output of slice are still references to the same arrays or objects contained in the original parent array. What that means to you *practically* is that changing an element or property in the nested arrays/objects returned from `slice` will also change the same element or property within the nested array or object contained in the original parent array.